# How to select subnetworks, or regions, with a certain number of nodes or edges with RCy3

Tags: r, nodes, edges, cytoscape

[image]In R-controlled Cytoscape, I would like to select nodes within regions with more than two nodes OR more than one edge. With the code below, nodes 1, 4 and 5 get selected. My goal is to select only nodes 4 and 5 (see image above).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

David

```
library(RCy3)
nodes <- data.frame(
  id = c("node 0","node 1","node 2","node 3", "node 4", "node 5"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

edges <- data.frame(
  source = c("node 0","node 0","node 0","node 2", "node 4"),
  target = c("node 1","node 2","node 3","node 3", "node 5"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

createNetworkFromDataFrames(nodes, edges, title = "test")

createDegreeFilter(
  filter.name = 'degree filter',
  criterion = c(2,3),
  predicate = 'IS_NOT_BETWEEN')
```

Comment: Hi David,

I'm a bit confused.  You said that you wanted to select nodes within regions with more than two nodes OR more than one edge, which would be nodes 0, 2, and 3, right?  You could do a little more in your code to find the connected components, and then run your filter only on the connected components with only 2 nodes.

Comment: Hi Scoote, thanks for your reply.r, Yeah sorry, I used the verb "select", which is confusing. Nodes 0 to 3 are the ones that interest me. Thus, my idea was to select nodes 4 and 5 in order to remove them. But, using the code above, node 1 is also selected, and I do not want to remove it. Since my post, I have manage to created a variable that allows me to make the right choice, but I still wonder if there is some RCy3 that eludes me to make things easier.